# Can I change my dates of travel to the UK after filling out the online form?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I have successfully applied and made payment for UK visa around 26th February. Intended date of travel I wrote on the form was 4th April which I wanted to change to mid-May but just could not because once the form is committed one can't change it. To no avail I also tried contacted the visa office and the British High Commission. Now my appointment date is 8th April, can I make a requisition for changing the date as I will not be able to travel before mid may and I would not want to risk if they issue me a visa for three months from my intended date of travel then I may not be able to make proper use of my visa and travel at all..

Comment: Very normal. After you print out the form you cross out the date with a pen and put a new one above it.

Comment: @pnuts Considering the question was asked 6 months ago - and the OP probably has gone through the interview by now, it would be interesting to know what he did and how it went.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

For the sake of an answer, to repeat a Comment from @Gayot Fow:

> Very normal. After you print out the form you cross out the date with a pen and put a new one above it.